# Rails ActiveRecord best practice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm a bit of a Rails/AR newb, so apologies for the simple question.  I have the following classes:

```
Account
User (has many Organizations, has one base Account, has access to many Accounts through permission from owner)
Organization (has many Users, has one Account)
```

Objects can belong to Organizations but I also want Users to be able to own them directly, so I added the Account class to make for single ownership.  Each User and Organization should have exactly one owned Account, but Users should have access to many Accounts through a permissions list specified by the owner of the Account.

Given that I have a join table called user_account_roles:

```
user_account_roles:
  account_id
  user_id
  role
```

This is where I'm getting stuck:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :owned_account, :through => :user_account_roles
  has_many :accounts, :through => :user_account_roles
end
```

Two specific questions:

1. Can I somehow specify that a user has an owned account which is designated by the row existing in the join table and role=owner.  Something like has_one :owned_account, :through => :user_account_roles, :condition => (role="owner")?  If that doesn't work, should I add another column to the user table specifying its account ID?
2. Can I use those two associations in a single class?  (I want user.owned_account to return the account it owns and user.accounts to return the full list of accounts a user has access to)

Comment: What do you mean by `objects`?

Comment: `has access to many Accounts through permission from owner` use role model and set different roles